# Before_action ignored rails 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I have a problem with the before_action with rail 4.1.5, it seems like totally ignored by my new application.

I'm trying to use I18n in my app, i followed the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Set current language to user params[:locale] if exists otherwise, the default_locale is used(en)
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

end
```

My 'big' controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ActionController::Base
  def helloworld
  end
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "/:locale" do
    get '/' => 'welcome#helloworld'
  end 
end
```

en.yml:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world !"
```

fr.yml:

```
fr:
  hello: "Bonjour le monde !"
```

I've tried to change the I18n.locale directly in my controller like that and it works...

```
class WelcomeController < ActionController::Base
  def helloworld
    I18n.locale = :fr
  end
end
```

That's why i think my before_action is ignored, but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're inheriting from `ActionController::Base` in both cases.  If you want the before action to run in all controllers inherit all of them from your `ApplicationController`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def helloworld
  end
end
```